# PHP - Get variable from database based on another variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to do some database projects for school in a self pace class, so I don't know much of the syntax. I am trying to change a row of by database based on the ID given.

Heres some pseudocode of what I want to accomplish:

```
if(databaseRowWithThis$id name == x) 
   UPDATE database SET name = '$name' WHERE id='$id';
```

If this is confusing, please tell me and I'll try to clear it up.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

PHP with Syntax

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$login,$pw,$database);   // connection info

$sql = "UPDATE yourtablename SET name= ? WHERE id=?";   // placeholders for parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);  // prepare the query
if($stmt){
  $stmt->bind_param("is",$id,$name);   // bind the parameters to the ?, i for integers, s for string, must be in exact order as the query
  $stmt->execute();  // execute
  $stmt->close();  // close statement
}
$conn->close(); // close the connection
```